# SQLite :memory: Indexes are still writing to disk

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to get SQLite to operate fully in memory. I'm using the following connection string:

```csharp
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=:memory:;Synchronous=OFF;
    Journal Mode=OFF;Cache Size=10000");
```

I write 10,000,000 inserts wrapped in a transaction - this happens as fast as I would expect and does not touch the disk.

As soon as I start creating indexes on the table, the IO spikes and I can see it is writing temp files to the AppData folder.

I assume there is a setting/PRAGMA I am missing, but I haven't found it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled with the settings some more and increased both the page size and cache size:

```
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=:memory:;Synchronous=OFF;
            Journal Mode=OFF;Cache Size=1000000;Page Size=8192;");
```

I believe when the total pages were exhausted it started writing to the temp store. I tried to set the temp_store pragma, but it wasn't having any effect - it's possible that the version I'm using was compiled to override that setting.

Either way, having a larger page size and a higher number of total pages allowed both the table and indexes to stay in memory.